# Biasing a transistor

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bias

When biasing an AC Transistor amplifier circuit, does it bias the AC current/voltage by shifting the output wave up, or does it actually amplify it and change the amplitude of the output wave?

Comment: A CE (for example) transistor amplifier amplifies the signal, changing the amplitude.  If there's a DC component that gets amplified too, which is why capacitor coupling is common.  Not really sure what you're asking the way your question is worded.  The biasing of the transistor just establishes an operating point that allows for useful linear amplification. (Usually)  Other topologies like emitter follower don't provide voltage amplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Biasing* generally refers to the DC operating point in quiescient state.  There is therefore no AC to shift or amplify.

The point of biasing something like a audio amplifier is to put the operating point near the middle of the range the circuit can do.  The incoming AC signal then adds and subtracts from that.  With the quiescient operating point in the middle, the amplitude of the AC signal the circuit can handle is maximized.  The output signal is no good when it clips against either end.  With the operating point in the middle, the nearest distance to clipping - in either direction - is maximized.

Comment: Biasing is also used to minimize distortion in class A-B amplifiers.